# Trying to find out the name/episode of b&w tv episode--1950's or 1960's science fiction/horror genre maybe

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

Three obese women are used for breeding while served and catered to by several little people, midgets, while a young, pretty, feminist career woman looks on in horror, soon to share same fate.  Maybe called "Three Witches" or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

It's reminiscent of the John Wyndham short story ["Consider Her Ways"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consider_Her_Ways) in which a woman takes experimental drugs and travels to a future where there are no men and women live according to a rigid caste system.  Apparently this was made into a 1964 episode of [The Alfred Hitchcock Hour](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQJy-HYfMio).

Comment: Yes, this is an unusual story and mirrors Wyndham's Consider Her Ways. He was based in London and a favorite of the BBC in the 60's Sci boom that led to the TV series Dr Who. At times his work went uncredited and he wrote under sevearl names for the US pulp fiction market (e.g. Wonder Stories. On the BBC TV series Out of the Unknown around 1964, he had at least two novellas dramatised, Random Qwest and No Place Like Earth. The black & white series is available on Amazon, sadly not Youtube / Vimeo as the Beeb keep banning the uploads, bless them. If your interested in JW and this type of though

Comment: @Applefanboy I've converted your post into a comment where it belongs. Please checkout the [tour] or ping a Diamond Mod in [chat] if you're still confused.

Comment: Noted, yes I have read the Tour information thanks.